# Trigger valueChange with Initialized value - angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, valuechangelistener, ngoninit

I'm writing an angular2 application and I'm stuck with something.
First of all, I have a select which is bind to a `formControl` :

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  profilesBy: Observable<any[]>;
  myControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.profilesBy = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .map(text => new formatQuery(text.value))
      .switchMap(body => this.getGroupBy(body, this.url), (_, res)=> res.json().aggregations.group_by_type.buckets);
  }
}
```

so, `myControl` is the `formControl`, and `profilesBy` is an Observable of an array.
The `formatQuery` just format a body for the query using the value of the select and `getGroupBy` return an `http` request (ie : http.post(url, body) ... ).
Then I assign the response : `res.json().aggregations.group_by_type.buckets`
But don't give too much thought about this.

Here is my template :

```html
<md-card>
    <h4>Profiles group by :
        <select [formControl]="myControl">
            Some options ...
        </select>
    </h4>

    <div *ngFor="let profile of profilesBy | async">
        <strong>{{profile.key}} :</strong> {{profile.doc_count | number:'1.0-2'}}
    </div>
</md-card>
```

And it works just fine when the user selects a value, it triggers the `valueChanges` and chains the actions!

So I'm happy with it. I think this is an elegant way to do so, instead of using `ngOnChanges()`

Now here is where I can't find a way to make it works. Basically, I want to initialize the select with a value and trigger (without any user action) the `valueChange`

I tried to used [(ngModel)] : `<select [formControl]="myControl" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupBy">`
but it didn't trigger the it.

Last, I tried to make the call myself in the method `ngOnInit()`

```js
this.getGroupBy(new formatQuery(this.selectedGroupBy.value), this.url)
       .subscribe((response) => {
         this.profilesBy = response.json().aggregations.group_by_type.buckets;
       });
```

But I got a `Array` instead of an `Observable of Array`! What do I miss?
How can I make it work?

---

Possible solution using [startWith](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-startWith)

```js
this.profilesBy = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .startWith(DEFAULT)
      .map(text => new formatQuery(text.value))
      .switchMap(body => this.getGroupBy(body, this.url), (_, res)=> res.json().aggregations.group_by_type.buckets);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The possible solution is to use [startWith](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) operator:

```
this.profilesBy = this.myControl.valueChanges
  .startWith(DEFAULT_OPTION)
  .map(text => new formatQuery(text.value))
  .switchMap(body => ...);
```

Comment: But startWith is added in every new Observable from triggered from valueChanges, how to do only once?

Answer (score 6):

To change the value of a formControl programatically, you just have to call the [`setValue()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html#!#setValue-anchor) method:

> ```
> setValue(value: any, {onlySelf, emitEvent, emitModelToViewChange, emitViewToModelChange}?: {
>     onlySelf?: boolean,
>     emitEvent?: boolean,
>     emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
>     emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
>   }) : void
> ```
>
> Set the value of the form control to value.

so for your case : `this.myControl.setValue(foo)` should trigger the `valueChanges`.

Comment: Hi @n00dl3, Thank you for your answer.
I can't make it work though.

constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.profilesBy = this.myControl.valueChanges
      //.startWith(this.groupBy[0])
      .map(text => new formatQuery(text.value))
      .switchMap(body => this.getGroupBy(body, this.url), (_, res)=> res.json().aggregations.group_by_type.buckets);
     
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.setValue(this.groupBy[0]);
  }

Comment: Well I can't edit my previous comment ...
Do you know why it did not work ?

Comment: This should be the answer